# Why isn't the Left sidebar height changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I need to set the height of the left sidebar, based on the height of the content. This is the error I'm getting

> sidebarheight.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no
>   method 'ready'

I have jquery loaded, and a reeeeally basic few lines of js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").css({'height':($("#right").height()+'px')});
});
```

basic html structure

```
<div id="left">sidebar content</div>
<div id="right">page content</div>
```

see the working copy here: http://keganquimby.com/122sk

Comment: You should not mix several libraries like JQuery and Prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try this code using jQuery instead of $ it works:

```
jQuery("#left").css({'height':jQuery("#right").height()+'px'});
```

Well, at least, at the URL you provided, if you exceute this code sidebar height seems to change if they are not equal.

Comment: Yes, of course, jQuery.ready is needed, I was just talking about the inside code.

Answer (score 2):

You have prototype on your site and it's also using `$`.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // This way you have no conflict with the $. In here $ refers to jQuery. All other places $ refers to document.getElementById (From prototype)
    $("#left").css({'height':($("#right").height()+'px')});
});
```

---

So actually whats going on is:

```
$(document) -> document.getElementById(document)* -> null
->
null.ready -> "sidebarheight.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ready'"
```

> * Think $(...) returns a prototype GLOBAL.Element collection

`null` is Object?

> Yes

```
alert(typeof null); // object
```

---

And.....

`jQuery(document).ready(...` can be shorted `jQuery(...`:

```
jQuery(function($) { // This way you have no conflict with the $. In here $ refers to jQuery all other places et's refers to document.getElementById (From prototype)
    $("#left").css({'height':($("#right").height()+'px')});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something is wrong with your scripts references, check it out, cause in console of browser i can't call the jquery methods of functions , try this in console and will get error:

```
var div = $('<div></div>')
undefined
div.fadeIn()
TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeIn' of null
```

the `$` isn't referenced to jQuery ether because it's not included on the page or is in conflict with another liberty.